# Too many redirects after store name change

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, redirect, server-setup, localhost

I am using Magento 1.7 on localhost over WAMP server.

I wanted to change the name of my store, and I did so by going to `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Insecure / Secure`. Here I changed from `oldStoreName` to `newStoreName`.

I also changed my store's folder name, under `wamp64/www`, from `oldStoreName` to `newStoreName`.

I also changed the name of the alias file (under `wamp64/alias`) to `newStoreName.conf`, and changed the places within the file where `oldStoreName` appears.

I cleared Magento's `cache`. I cleared `var/session` folder. I cleared my browser's cookies and cache.

I am able to access my admin page, `127.0.0.1/newStoreName/admin` but **whenever I try to access `127.0.0.1/newStoreName` I get an error from the browser saying 'Too many redirects'**.

I checked Apache's error log and found "*apache client denied by server configuration local.xml*", but after a bit of research it didn't seem to be related to my issue. Maybe it is?

*Edit: here's the code of `.htaccess` under `myMagentoFolder/media/`:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone has any hints on what the issue could be? I just changed my store's name, didn't modify more things that what I explain here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check Your .htaccess file for redirects

Comment: As Konrad Siamro said, you should check `.htaccess` file if that is ok, remove the cache and try to reindex all the indexex ( it will be best if you could do it from CMD/shell )

Comment: I don't really know what my .htaccess should look like. I am pretty new in this field. I just added my .htaccess code, could you please tell me if you see something wrong?

Comment: Finally it was an issue related with an Observer that I'm using to prevent users from seeing some content before log in.